# Android toolbar layout

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

I have tried for almost two days trying to figure out how to make a simple custom toolbar layout like this :

[image]

I really can't figure out, how to increase the height of the toolbar or at least how to get that effect. Could you please give me some tips?
Thanks!

Comment: SInce you want that in a `Toolbar` Just add a `Toolbar` and Inside add an `Horizontal LinearLayout`. Add a `Layout` and `ImageView` as children and give the layout a weight of 2 and `ImageView` a weight of 1

Comment: hi, after checking below answer, please tell me if problem still happens

Answer (score 0):

To increase height of the Toolbar:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/HEIGHT_THAT_YOU_WANT">
```

As `Toolbar` is a `ViewGroup` you can do whatever you want within opening and closing tags. Just think it is `LinearLayout`.  Use several nested layouts to achieve what you want and in the end close it with the closing tag.

```
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not really follow material design, something I recommend.

Try this pseudo-code

```
<Toolbar>
  <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
      <EditText/>
      <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView src="smallImage"/>
        <ImageView src="smallImage"/>
        <ImageView src="smallImage"/>
        <ImageView src="smallImage"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView src="BigImage"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

You then need to set the width/height that better serves your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the tips! I finally did it! I'll just post the solution just in case someone needs it.

1) First of all I created a file in res/layout called toolbar.xml which contains

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView5" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"`
                />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button2" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Or

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jHEk.png)

2) Add the toolbar.xml to the main_activity.xml, so

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tbr.qps3.MainActivity">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        ...
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

3) Now just inflate it in onCreate() method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


}
```

Hope it helps!